# Is there a regex to match empty string and a given word at the same time?

Tags: regex

The value I'm trying to match to can either be a word OR it can be empty.

I need a regex that will do one of the following:

1. Match the word 'default' or empty string

OR

1. Match any non empty string that is not 'default'

The non empty string is important because "" is the same as default in my situation.

Is there a regex for this?

Anything that helps point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, the regex is pretty simple:

```
/^(|default)$/
```

Comment: This gets me further down the road.  I've learned now that it isn't JUST empty string, the parameter may not exist at all.  sigh.  Thanks for your help you solved the immediate problem.

Answer (score 4):

The ? means 0 or 1 occurrence:

```
  /^(default)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use (yourword)?

```
val regex = Regex("\\d+ ?(degree(s)?)? [a-zA-Z]+ (to|in) ?(degree(s)?)? [a-zA-Z]+")

val str = "123 degrees celsius in degrees Kelvins"

println(str.matches(regex))
enter code here
```